# Excel VBA Macro's to clear data containing specific cell

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to create an excel macro VBA to clear some specific cell (F4,H4,H5,H6,H7,F8,H8,F9,H9,H14) value and assigning the same macro to button. But it's not working. Could someone please help by correcting macro.

```
Sub Clear()
   Range("F4,H4,H5,H6,H7,F8,H8,F9,H9,H14").Clear
End Sub
```

Regards
RKP

Comment: make sure you assign the worksheet to the range. `Worksheet("Sheet1").Range("F4,H4,H5,H6,H7,F8,H8,F9,H9,H14").Clear`

Comment: Works fine for me, what's the issue you're having? Scott Craner is correct though. You should assign it to a worksheet; otherwise it will work on `ActiveSheet`

Comment: What type of Button are you using, if its a Form button, double click on the button while on Design Mode and either copy your code under that buttons subroutine or just type the name of your macro so when the button is clicked the macro will be called...

Comment: Hi Scott and Maldred,

I have updated the code as below.

Sub Clrcont()

Worksheet("Page1").Range("F4,H4,H5,H6,H7,F8,H8,F9,H9,H14").Clear

End Sub

And I am getting an error "Object doesn't support this property or method".

Regards
RKP

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for helping me with the code. Below is the working code.

Sub ClearContent()

```
Range("H5:I5").Select
Selection.ClearContents

Range("F7:I7").Select
Selection.ClearContents

Range("F8").Select
Selection.ClearContents

Range("H8:I8").Select
Selection.ClearContents

Range("H9:I9").Select
Selection.ClearContents

Range("F14:I14").Select
Selection.ClearContents

Range("F15:I15").Select
Selection.ClearContents
```

End Sub